# CORS + sendAjax + authentication

Tags: ajax, couchdb, cors, phantomjs, casperjs

I am using casperjs and have run more 1000 test runs. I was using sendAjax function to fetch json objects from couchdb and it was working without any issue.

Yes I do have --web-security in my grunt file and using phantomjs with linux mint 13 64 bit.

I can access the data manually by log in to couchdb interface and use the url to fetch the records from the database. I am unable to fetch the data from couchdb using the script below.

```js
  var url = 'http://worksite.com:5984/draft/_design/WidgetData/_view/by_rootIdforTest?include_docs=true&startkey="52210def794e1e7a8dd8e74b8b0ab5a6"&endkey="52210def794e1e7a8dd8e74b8b0ab5a6"'
  var jsonObject = casper.evaluate(function(url) {
    try {
      return JSON.parse(__utils__.sendAJAX(url, 'GET', null, false));
    } catch (e) {}
  }, {
    url: url
  });
  return jsonObject;
```

Modified script and added authentication credentials but request is not being authorized

```
  var url = 'http://worksite.com:5984/draft/_design/WidgetData/_view/by_rootIdforTest?include_docs=true&startkey="52210def794e1e7a8dd8e74b8b0ab5a6"&endkey="52210def794e1e7a8dd8e74b8b0ab5a6"'
  var jsonObject = casper.evaluate(function(url) {
    try {
      return JSON.parse(__utils__.sendAJAX(url, 'GET', {
        "name": "username",
        "password",
        "mypassword"
      }, false));
    } catch (e) {}
  }, {
    url: url
  });

  return jsonObject;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *unable to fetch the data*. Is there any error? What does the evaluate call return? Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Is that a typo in your second listing? Should it be `"password":"mypassword"` ?  (Also, as I mentioned on the casperjs mailing list, have you tried with both PhantomJS and SlimerJS. If it works with one, but not the other, that really narrows down where the problem might lie.)